# How can I use FFmpeg convert the audio codec of a video file?

Tags: macos, audio, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

I have a large group of videos with an audio codec of **AAC**, I need the codec to be **Linear PCM**. How can I do this without re-transcoding the video? I am a command line novice and may need the basics explained.

I'll be using OS X

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'd use: `ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le outfile.mov`.

Comment: Does ffmpeg mux PCM in MP4?

Comment: Only when muxing in mov, not mp4 - fixed answer.

Comment: Thanks! From what I've read I can't run this on the original file, I'll have to output new files then delete the old ones is that right? And to run that above command on entire directory with sub folders it's something to do with echo? Like I said, I'm a novice at the command line.</br>

Comment: Correct. Help with writing this to a temp file and overwriting/removing old file after successful completion is largely shell programming :)